# VCPKG_FORCE_SYSTEM_BINARIES Errors when Running vcpkg on raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, vcpkg

I installed the latest version of cmake and was following [some instructions i made](https://github.com/advra/grpc-vcpkg-boilerplate-example) to integrate a project that used vcpkg with grpc. After installing vcpkg I try to install package with `./vcpkg install grpc` which resulted in the error bellow. The instructions worked on a OSX and Ubuntu but I run into issues with raspberry pi.

I have set tried both `0` and `1` like so `$VCPKG_FORCE_SYSTEM_BINARIES=1` but neither option is working. Using `./vcpkg` result in a VCPKG_FORCE_SYSTEM_BINARIES error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/vcpkg $ ./vcpkg 
Environment variable VCPKG_FORCE_SYSTEM_BINARIES must be set on arm and s390x platforms.
pi@raspberrypi:~/vcpkg $ VCPKG_FORCE_SYSTEM_BINARIES=1
pi@raspberrypi:~/vcpkg $ echo $VCPKG_FORCE_SYSTEM_BINARIES
1
pi@raspberrypi:~/vcpkg $ ./vcpkg 
Environment variable VCPKG_FORCE_SYSTEM_BINARIES must be set on arm and s390x platforms.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In bash the environment variable is set with export:

```
export VCPKG_FORCE_SYSTEM_BINARIES=1
./vcpkg install grpc
```

The export command can be put in .bashrc to persist this setting.

src: https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/14140